# Using grepl in R to match string

Tags: r, sapply, grepl

I have a frame data "testData" as follows:

```
id     content
 1     I came from China
 2     I came from America
 3     I came from Canada
 4     I came from Japan
 5     I came from Mars
```

And I also have another frame data "addr" as follows:

```
id   addr
 1   America
 2   Canada
 3   China
 4   Japan
```

Then how can I use `grepl`, `sapply` or any other useful function in R to generate data into as follows:

```
id   content               addr
 1   I came from China     China
 2   I came from America   America
 3   I came from Canada    Canada
 4   I came from Japan     Japan
 5   I came from Mars      Mars
```

Comment: my testData are twittes posted by users. so they are not as neat as this sample. I can only use grep or grepl to find if each testData.content contains any words in addr I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
vec = addr$addr

testData$addr = apply(testData, 1, function(u){
    bool = sapply(vec, function(x) grepl(x, u[['content']]))
    if(any(bool)) vec[bool] else NA
})
```

Comment: sorry, I can't use gsub. For the real data is not so neat. They are twitters posted by real people. I want  to find if these twitter has some specific words in it. If any twitter has any specific words which I want to find. then these words will be added to the twitter, or not

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to replicate the column and remove "I came from "

```
testData$addr <- gsub("I came from ", testData$content)
```

Comment: sorry, maybe I didn't make it clear. In my real data, there may be kinds of text. e.g. "it is China", "He comes from China, but not real" and so on. Anyway, I can't use gsub or regex to do it. I can only use grepl to find if each row of testData contains any words in addr(or another string vector). If it does, the word will be added to the row, or not.

Comment: then you should add examples like that in the original question. Why can't you use regex? Is this a homework question?

Comment: Sorry, the example I posed is not a good one. Since the words I want to search in the text is not decided. And the testData$content is complicated. So I think I can only use grepl to search words in the text. This is not a homework question. I met it when I am handling another task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude solution using some `tidyverse` functions:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "id     content
 1     'it is China'
 2     'She is in America now'
 3     'Canada is over there'
 4     'He comes from Japan'
 5     'I came from Mars'", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 = read.table(text = "id   addr
 1   America
 2   Canada
 3   China
 4   Japan
 5   Mars", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
crossing(df1, df2 %>% select(addr)) %>% # this creates a data frame of every possible content and add combination
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(str_detect(content, add)) # str_detect is the same as grepl, though the arguments are reversed. This filters to only observations where addr is in content.

# A tibble: 5 x 3
     id content               addr   
  <int> <chr>                 <chr>  
1     1 it is China           China  
2     2 She is in America now America
3     3 Canada is over there  Canada 
4     4 He comes from Japan   Japan  
5     5 I came from Mars      Mars
```